# Как установить набор символов по умолчанию в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Здравствуйте.
Очень не удобно каждый раз менять в проекте набор символов с юникода на многобайтовую кодировку в Visual Studio 2015 при создании новых проектов.

Как задать многобайтувую кодировку по умолчанию при создании будущих проектов, а не изменять ее каждый раз в свойствах?

[image: окно настройки набора символов проекта]